# How to convert war file into original file (extracted form)?

Tags: file, directory, war

I have a war file and I want to convert it to original file, is it any way to convert war file into original file through command prompt

Comment: What do you mean by "Original file"? Do you want to extract it ?

Comment: Rename it to .zip :)

Comment: yes, is it any way to convert through command prompt

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options :
1. use "jar xvf myfolder.war" to extract the files
2. Use WinZip to open the war file and then extract the files that you need.

Comment: Please check (✓) the answer. If it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jar -xvf warfilename.war`.